# ASP.NET: How to remove the file name.aspx from URLs

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule for web.config file so that the url will remove the file name from it, meaning:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/Index.aspx
http://www.example.com/admin/Product.aspx
```

will become:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/
http://www.example.com/admin/
```

AND:

```
http://www.example.com/Index.aspx
http://www.example.com/Product.aspx
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/Product/
```

tried a couple of codes found online, but all of them gave me internal error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using IIS6 or IIS7? Can you provide an example of the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the open source UrlRewriter to do that on a number of projects, it works very well

http://urlrewriter.net/

In order to make it work you must add it to your web.config file, like so:

```
<httpModules>
    <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
</httpModules>
```

And add a routing section as well, they have good documentation, but basically you provide rewrite-rules, that could look something like this:

```
<rewriter>    
    <rewrite url="~/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" to="~/$1.aspx" />
</rewriter>
```

Add the UrlRewriter dll-files to your bin, and set IIS to handle wildcards:

1. Find site in IIS Manager (inetmgr)
2. Open properties on your site
3. Go to tab "Home Directory"
4. Click "Configuration" under Application Settings
5. Click "Insert" under "Wildcard application maps"
6. Put path to .NET executable (same as the one used for handling .aspx files) in the "Executable" field
7. Uncheck "Verify file exists"
8. Press "OK"

And you are done :)

It's quite a good solution for WebForms projects, but make sure you test it well, and verify that GoogleBot can still access your site.

Comment: hey thanks alot for the info, but i wasn't able to figure out how to install it on Windows Server 2008 and IIS6.. is it possible? is there an easier way of doing this? I just want to remove the "Filename.aspx" from the url, only the filename and extension.

Comment: There might be simpler ways to it .. Step 5 "Insert wildcard application maps" could be used to it perhaps? If you add a wildcard that takes a file name without extension and handles it with .NET (step 5-6), and checks if the file exists, you might get away with just renaming the "file.aspx" to "file" without extension? I'm not sure it will work, and if it does it is quite hacky, but you could try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if you have it but with IIS7 there is a module that you can install that you can set up url rewriting rules. It will add the appropriate rules to the web.config of your site

a guide by Scott Guthrie of Microsoft may help - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. but i have IIS6 running on windows server 2008. will I still be able to do this?